# Access to the same Exchange Server account using the IMAP protocol and Microsoft Outlook

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, imap, exchange-server

I am developing a .NET C# application that will access the Exchange Server using the IMAP protocol. The application will retrieve emails, mark them as read, and move them from Inbox to some other folder based on some predefined rules.

My question is, will the user that will be accessing same email account using the Outlook (Exchange Server account configuration) see the same email structure (e.g. same emails will be read and emails will appear in appropriate folders) as it was made through the IMAP?

I do not have access to the Exchange Server to be able to validate this.

Thanks in advance,
Srdjan

Answer (score 0):

Typically yes.  However, it depends upon the mail client. If they are using Outlook, then yes, as Outlook will refresh various properties on the messages (and have them disappear if they were moved or deleted).

Answer (score 0):

yes. The Outlook will see the same structure and messages in the same folders as your application accessing exchange server via IMAP.